# Making my player model invisible to my camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

So, in FPS games there is a thing where you can only see your hands, not body, but other players do see your model and animations. Is there a way to do this in Unity?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's usually done by just sorting out what's being rendered client side and what's being rendered server-side.

E.g The client-side view will render only the hands overlay and other player models. Depending on how you do your multiplayer, it'll just be a case of just disabling the renderer of the player model and enabling it for other players.